# How to extract data from excel sheet and display it with shiny?

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to program a small app using shiny. I have an excel sheet with some data in the background out of which I want to extract a specific column indicated in the input. The data in this column should then simply be displayed in the output.

The excel sheet named "test.xlsx" looks like this:

```
USA China India
2   5     6
```

My code right now looks like this:

```
library(shiny)
library(xlsx)
library(dplyr)

#Save country names ----
country <- c("USA", "China", "India")

ui <- fluidPage( 
#Create select input button with countries as options ----
  selectInput(inputId = "coun",
              label = "Country",
              choices = c("", country),
              selected = NULL,
              multiple = FALSE),
#Create action button ----
  actionButton(inputId = "go", 
               label = "View"),
#Final text output ----
  textOutput("text")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
#Extract respective column in R code ----
  data <- eventReactive(input$go, {
    x <- read.xlsx("test.xlsx", 1)
    (x$input$coun)
  })
#Output text ----
  output$text <- renderText({data})
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

This code however produces the error message "argument 1 (type 'closure') cannot be handled by 'cat'".

I am very new using shiny so I would appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0):

I used to have this type of error, most of the time, "type closure" are produced when you want to manipulate reactive objects omitting "()", in your case it seems that

```
output$text <- renderText({data})
```

should be

```
output$text <- renderText({data()})
```

Suggestion :

```
library(shiny)
library(xlsx)
library(dplyr)

#Save country names ----
country <- c("USA", "China", "India")

ui <- fluidPage( 
  #Create select input button with countries as options ----
  selectInput(inputId = "coun",
              label = "Country",
              choices = c("", country),
              selected = NULL,
              multiple = FALSE),
  #Create action button ----
  actionButton(inputId = "go", 
               label = "View"),
  #Final text output ----
  textOutput("text")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  #Extract respective column in R code ----
  data <- eventReactive(input$go, {
    x <- read.xlsx("test.xlsx", 1)
    z <- x %>% select(input$coun)
    return(z)
  })
  #Output text ----
  output$text <- renderText({data()})
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Thank you. The error has disappeared however now there is no text output produced when I click the "View" button. Do you have any idea what is wrong with that?

Comment: Maybe you should try to affect your filtered data to an other variable and then use return to affect it to data()

Comment: Could you supply an example for that?Sorry, I am new and not sure how to do this.

Comment: Is it possible to have the structure of the data, few lines with header ?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean with that, I have a MWE displayed in the questions above and I added some explanatory lines.

Comment: I mean the structure of the data, the number,names of columns and datatype. Like the output of  head(data) in r

Comment: Oh sure, the data is just the simple table displayed above the MWE. So basically three columns (USA, China, India) and one row containing a value for each country (2, 5, 6). When selecting a country with selectInput, the output should be the respective value for the country. Does that make sense?

Comment: See the code that I've include in my edited answer, however I havn't tested it

Comment: Unfortunately, this code does not produce any output for me and the error 'Unknown column' appears.